# Show video stream in Android application use specific link in rtsp

Tags: android, kotlin, video-streaming, surfaceview, rtsp

I try to show video stream in Android application use SurfaceView, Kotlin, and I need use this link

```
rtsp://192.168.8.73/cdb6e5a0-23af-40e8-8da8-54a21af9cba3/cdb6e5a0-23af-40e8-8da8-54a21af9cba3_vs1?token=cdb6e5a0-23af-40e8-8da8-54a21af9cba3^LVEBAMPZOTDGU|admin|1522055956266|0|0^50^26^26^1522315156^3394fa4fd8888fcca38c10bcf5fa74748b5b58a1&username=admin
```

When i make player.prepare() - I get error java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x64

Please tell me how to play streaming video use this link on Android

Comment: Have you tried playing that stream using existing Android apps? Does the device have access to that server? Also note that your URL is invalid, as it contains invalid characters that are not URL-encoded (e.g., `^`).

Comment: I wrote an application that should show streaming video, and tested another links and my code work, but with this link - not working. As far as I understood, I do not need access to the server. And my colleague said that on ios this link works, but he using some kind of library... and yet you assume that the link is invalid due to incorrect characters?

Comment: "As far as I understood, I do not need access to the server" -- sure you do. Otherwise, the data cannot flow from the server to the client. "and yet you assume that the link is invalid due to incorrect characters?" -- see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/115145).